# I'm trying to highlight a table header when it is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the code pasted below from index.html.haml. The "if" condition is never returning true and the color is not changing, can anyone tell me why its not returning true

```
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      - if @sort_type == 'title'
        %th.hilite= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort_type => "title"), id:"title_header"
      - else
        %th= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort_type => "title"), id:"title_header"
      %th Rating
      - if @sort_type == 'release'
        %th.hilite= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort_type => "release"), id:"release_date_header"
      - else
        %th= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort_type => "release"), id:"release_date_header"
      %th More Info
```

Comment: its doing sort as expected, but some how the condition @sort_type == 'title' is failing. Is there anything i have to change in this view file or in the controller. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is assigned to @sort_type in controller.
There must be somewhere

```
@sort_type = :title
```